# JavaFX application Window freezes when trying to show the backgroud process status

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on an application feature to show the progress status in `TextArea`. And I'm using observer pattern to implement that. But when I try to append the status information to the `TextArea`, the Window freezes. How to solve that problem?

The freeze window like this :

[image: Window freezes]

When `doSomething()` is done. The freezes window back to normal. Like this:

[image: Window back to normal]

Here are my codes

```
start(Stage stage)


FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("view/progressStatus.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
statusStage = new Stage();
statusScene = new Scene(root);
statusStage.setScene(statusScene);
progressStatusController = loader.getController();
statusStage.show();
MyFiles myFiles = new MyFiles();
myFiles.addObserver(progressStatusController);
newMyFiles.doSomething();
```

```
public class ProgressStatusController implements Initializable, Observer {
    @FXML private ProgressBar progressBar;
    @FXML private TextArea textArea;
    private String[] message;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
        textArea.textProperty().set(textArea.getText().concat("\n").concat((String)arg));
        textArea.positionCaret(textArea.getText().length());
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to use [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) when modifying your TextArea in your `update` method.

Comment: How you are producing the result 1,2,3,4,5... do you use Thread.sleep(..)? are you calculating anything that produce that result? You shoudn't do extensive computations in JavaFX Thread.That MyFiles class is counting files into a Folder?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but still not working.

Comment: You're hiding the important part from us. How is the `update` method called from your `doSomething`? What therad does `doSomething` use for it's "heavy work"?

Comment: @GoXR3Plus That MyFiles class is counting files into a Folder? Yes, something like that. But where should I do that computation? How come my previous version works fine? That's a JDialog implements Observer. And also I add the status information to a JTextArea.

Comment: @fabian the `update` method will be called here `for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) { notify(String.valueOf(i)); }`.

Comment: On which thread does this run? On the one calling `doSomething()`???

Comment: @fabian  In each loop, I read something from a file, store it to a object.

Comment: @fabian Yes, On the one calling doSomething().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doSomething` is a long-running task and therefore should not be run on the JavaFX application thread. However the `start` method is run on this thread.

You need to run `doSomething` on a different thread to avoid blocking the application thread. Updates to the UI should be done on the application thread; therefore you should use `Platform.runLater` to execute the updates:

```
...
MyFiles myFiles = new MyFiles();
myFiles.addObserver(progressStatusController);
new Thread(newMyFiles::doSomething).start();
```

```
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    System.out.println(arg);
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n" + arg);
        textArea.positionCaret(textArea.getText().length());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `Fabian's` answer i recommend you to use JavaFX [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm).Service is running into a different than JavaFX Thread and you can do what you want there but be careful modifying JavaFX Nodes that are into the `SceneGraph` is not allowed so you have to use:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
   //your code...
});
```

> Typical example of Service for reading the files into a folder using
>   `Files.walk(..)` method + `Streams`:

```
 /**
     * With this Service you can count the files of a folder
     * it is a minimalistic example of the power of Services
     *
     */
    public class ServiceExample extends Service<Void> {

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public InputService() {

            setOnSucceeded(s ->{ 
                //code
            });
            setOnCancelled(c ->{ 
                //code
            });
            setOnFailed(c ->{ 
                //code
            });
        }



        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            return new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {

                    countFiles(new File("the path of the folder");

                    return null;
                }



                /**
                 * Count files in a directory (including files in all sub
                 * directories)
                 * 
                 * @param directory
                 *            the directory to start in
                 * @return the total number of files
                 */
                private int countFiles(File dir) {
                    if (dir.exists())
                        try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(dir.getPath()))) {
                            return (int) paths.filter(s -> { //where s is a File or Folder

                                // System.out.println("Counting..." +
                                // s.toString())

                                // cancelled?
                                if (isCancelled())
                                    paths.close();
                                else
                                  System.out.println(s);


                                return false;
                            }).count();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Main.logger.log(Level.WARNING, "", ex);
                        }

                    return 0;
                }


            };
        }

    }
```

Comment: Much appreciated!